# PRE_AUTH_FILTER + Login form authentication

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security

I'm new with spring security and it seems I have a question which is too difficult for me, for faqs and for other sites.

Task is:

1. I have spring app with login form. Everything works good.
2. Now I need to have ability to get any permitted page from app but with auth via URL... something like: http://myapp.de?login=test&password=test. I made it with PRE_AUTH_FILTER. Everything works with URL.
3. Problem is I need both auth way in my app. Let's say if PRE_AUTH_FILTER failed then standard login form is loaded. So: http://myapp.de will show my login form and in point 1).

Now with my security configuration I only have PRE_AUTH_FILTER working.

What did I miss?

```
<sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <sec:form-login login-page="/login.jsp" default-target-url="/start" authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error=true"/>
    <sec:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login.jsp"/>
    <sec:anonymous username="guest" granted-authority="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
    <sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/error403.jsp"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll"/>   
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/objautocomplete*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/start*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/u*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/crosstable*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/objcen*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/objchecks*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/globalcen*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <sec:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="preAuthFilter" />
    <sec:remember-me/>
</sec:http>

    <!-- PRE_ AUTHENTICATION -->        
<beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceImpl"
    class="com.grsnet.qvs.auth.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />

<beans:bean id="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint"
    class="com.grsnet.qvs.auth.LinkForbiddenEntryPoint" />

<beans:bean id="preAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" ref="userDetailsServiceImpl" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="preAuthFilter"
    class="com.grsnet.qvs.auth.UrlParametersAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="appControlAuthenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>

<sec:authentication-manager alias="appControlAuthenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="preAuthenticationProvider" />
</sec:authentication-manager>

    <!-- LOGIN FORM AUTHENTICATION -->  

<sec:authentication-manager>
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="qvsUserDetailsService"/>
</sec:authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="qvsUserDetailsService" class="com.grsnet.qvs.auth.QVSUserDetailsService"/>

</beans:beans>
```

**UPDATE** UrlParametersAuthenticationFilter.java

```
public class UrlParametersAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {

    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (request.getParameterMap().size() == 2) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String[] credentials = new String[2];
        credentials[0] = request.getParameter("j_username");
        credentials[1] = request.getParameter("j_password");
        return credentials;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<sec:custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="preAuthFilter" />
```

EDIT:

Yeah, the filter is a mess. Did you even look at the javadoc or source of the AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter? PreAuthentication is used when an external system has done the authentication already. For instance, if you use Java EE authentication provided by your container or you have a web-front that authenticates, like fronting with IIS for NTLM/kerberos.

Also, you have implemented it incorrectly, getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal() should return the user name, aka Principal and getPreAuthenticatedCredentials should return the password, aka Credentials. But more importantly, the AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter **does not do any authentication**. From the first line of the Javadoc:

```
Base class for processing filters that handle pre-authenticated authentication requests, where it is assumed that the principal has already been authenticated by an external system.
```

So, scrap your filter and use the standard UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

```
<beans:bean id="urlParameterAuthFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="usernameParameter" value="username" />
    <beans:property name="passwordParameter" value="password" />
    <beans:property name="postOnly" value="false" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="appControlAuthenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>
```

Then replace your custom filter declaration with

```
<sec:custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="urlParameterAuthFilter" />
```

Disclaimer: passing passwords in the URL is a really, really bad idea and you shouldn't do it in the first place. It will show up in access-logs and it introduces a whole bunch of really unnecessary security concerns.

Comment: Should I replace my code with your string? Or add it? When I replace I have next situation: 1. login form works 2. url auth does not work and redirects me on login form.

Comment: UPDATE: Have next exception: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken

Comment: UPDATE: and when I try to debug I have no any activities in userDetailsServiceImpl. When I had PRE_AUTH_FILTER I'd had debug activities and it had worked.

Comment: Can you post the code of your UrlParametersAuthenticationFilter

Comment: yes, please. Take a look on it in update section. By the way, I have all good debug activities in the UrlParametersAuthenticationFilter.java

Comment: OK, I see your disclaimer. Thank you. What do you advice? I use https... Maybe I can pass login+password inside POST request? It will be more secure. What should I do for it? The same as you write before? By the way, I tried your filter... Does not work. It redirects from url with login+pw onto login page. And does not use UserDetailsService.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I applied your offered code. Now when I enter login+pw on my login page I redirected to login page again. What code do should I public here to get some your help?  By the way, I see in debug my UserDetails object is created quite right. But then I see login page again.